# Command for this symbol looks like \mathcal{F}

Tags: fonts, symbols

[image: latex command for this symbol]

I can't find the LaTeX command and symbol and its package of this symbol. Can any one suggest me the command. I tried `\mathcal{F}` but its not exactly the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `euscript`'s `\EuScript`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{euscript}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{F} \neq \EuScript{F}$
\end{document}
```